Symfony app with doctrine: MariaDB to Postgres = column cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb
In the process of migrating from Mariadb to postgres 16 with these steps:
docker exec -ti app php bin/console doctrine:database:create
docker exec -ti app php bin/console make:migration
docker exec -ti app php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 

docker run --rm -it --platform linux/amd64 --network app_network -v ./pgloader.load:/pgloader.load dimitri/pgloader:latest \
     pgloader pgloader.load

docker exec -ti app php bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage

pgloader.load:
LOAD DATABASE
     FROM      mysql://root:root@database/dev
     INTO      pgsql://app:pass@postgres/dev

 WITH include drop, create tables

 ALTER SCHEMA 'dev' RENAME TO 'public';

I am getting into a stuck situation where my json migration is not working
php bin/console make:migration
generates
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json', nullable: true, options: ["jsonb" => true])]
    private $emoji;

if I look into the migration file:
  $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE blog ALTER emoji TYPE JSONB');

If I connect to the DB and look at the schema it is of type text
now everything works BUT doctrine says that migration has not been executed
if I do
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 

I get
  SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "emoji" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb  
  HINT:  You might need to specify "USING emoji::jsonb".  

